# Opposite of mutating

Tags: programming-languages, terminology

I am looking for an adjective; one that describes the opposite of "mutating". I want to use it to mark functions, methods and method parameters (including the receiver) as "not being mutated" by the function, similar how the D language does it.

Ds approach works pretty well for parameters:

```
class X {
    void foo(const int x, immutable char[] y) {
        // x is readonly
        // y is readonly and can be trusted not to change
    }
}
```

However, both `immutable` and `const` seem ugly when using them on the function/method itself to denote that the function does not modify the receiver object:

```
// again D
class X {
    private int x;

    void foo() const {
        // x becomes readonly because the method is marked s such
    }

    void foo2() immutable {
        // same as foo(): x is readonly
    }
}
```

I am looking for a keyword with the same semantics as the above keywords in D; but as an adjective to be written before the function name:

```
class X {
    private x: int
    non-mutating foo() {
        // x is readonly
    }
}
```

Using `immutable` reads like the method would be immutable (such as final in Java or non-Virtual in C#/C++). I cannot use the keyword after the parenthesis closing the parameter list because thats where the return type is supposed to go:

```
fun x() -> Int
```

---

I'm not entirely sure whether this is the correct place to ask this question. But since i did not find a `programming language design SE`, i figuerd the people knowing many programming languages in this community could give me a few pointers :)

Comment: If you are making a new language, just make immutable the default...

Comment: Creating a new language is tempting, but also a whole lot of work... I might decide to turn them into Java annotations and write maven plugin to verify

Comment: This is a valid question!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OO speak, functions that are known to change data are called *modifiers* and those that are known to just return something without change are called *selectors*. I do not hear the terms very often, somehow they are not popular. More popular are *getters* and *setters*.

So you could use the qualifiers *selector* and *modifier* or *getter* and *setter* respectively.

Most people would associate getter and setter with properties. This could be a reason to choose the other, seemingly forgotten terms.

If you are only interested in the mutability of specific arguments, *readonly* may be appropriate.

Comment: Thank you very much! I'll see where `selector fun x()` takes me

Comment: I think "getter and setter" came much later. The original Smalltalk terminology probably predates everything else.

Answer (score 0):

Your arguments about using `immutable` or `const` on method  names is unconvincing. It's done in C++ and D. What exactly is your objection? Why do you feel it's ugly?

You could always put them in a different spot, such as `void const funcName()` or `const void funcName()`, but you run into problems with the return type being `const`. Like if you want to return a `const` object, it would probably be declared as `const ObjectType funcName()`, so that's no good.

Swift and Haskell use `->` for return types, so maybe you could go with a syntax similar to that? You could do something like `const funcName -> Int` for a constant function that returns an `Int`. And then you could do `const funcName :: argumentType -> Int` for a constant function that takes an argument of `argumentType` and returns an `int`, or something along those lines.

Comment: Exactly that is what i am trying to do, sorry if that was not clear in the question. I want the result to be `immutable fun x() -> ReturnType`. The issue is that `immutable function` sounds like `final function`. Immmutable is not 100% correct, even, non-mutating is more on spot. But `non-mutating` cannot be a keyword for obvious reasons